# Building C# Class from JSON

Tags: c#, json, class

I'm using https://jsonutils.com/ to build C# classes from JSON but I'm stuck for the correct class for variationsChoices. The part of the JSON file I'm having problems with is:

```
{"orderItems": [
        {
            "itemId": "92953385-4ce1-44be-8a20-c3cc597dd4a7",
            "price": 325,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "itemId": "dd757994-1480-4450-ae47-6d7f87dbcc33",
            "price": 325,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "itemId": "912f7bbb-58e0-45cc-a7ec-f35987073941",
            "price": 70,
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "itemId": "75cb81b8-22fb-4a65-bcf8-17e0e7d41f88",
            "variations": [
                {
                    "title": {
                        "en_GB": "Spiced or plain"
                    },
                    "itemIds": [
                        "38319b13-eabc-4777-be55-b9d9b5e8be3b",
                        "997f4cd7-3e8c-4549-97cb-de8b26bdb304"
                    ],
                    "minNumAllowed": 1,
                    "maxNumAllowed": 1,
                    "displayType": "choice"
                }
            ],
            "variationsChoices": [
                [
                    {
                        "itemId": "997f4cd7-3e8c-4549-97cb-de8b26bdb304",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "price": 70,
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "itemId": "ee3f9e6f-b7e1-4740-b837-1d81692c60e9",
            "price": 1495,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "itemId": "d124f18a-274d-4bb4-b554-d810c1145462",
            "price": 280,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "itemId": "81253f1b-d8e2-4106-aebe-29e6298aba37",
            "price": 270,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "itemId": "4f677d74-7c5a-416b-b486-2e1bf3f170a1",
            "price": 325,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "itemId": "52229604-1829-4148-92be-930eff07bef5",
            "variations": [
                {
                    "title": {
                        "en_GB": "Option"
                    },
                    "itemIds": [
                        "1230916c-3d2d-4a4b-9aff-55815924e13f",
                        "86bef61f-a59f-4c1f-88a6-009594ed1f54"
                    ],
                    "minNumAllowed": 1,
                    "maxNumAllowed": 1,
                    "displayType": "choice"
                }
            ],
            "variationsChoices": [
                [
                    {
                        "itemId": "86bef61f-a59f-4c1f-88a6-009594ed1f54",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "price": 995,
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
```

}

jsonutils returns the following classes but public IList<IList<>> variationsChoices { get; set; }is not value C#

```
public class Title
{
    public string en_GB { get; set; }
}

public class Variation
{
    public Title title { get; set; }
    public IList<string> itemIds { get; set; }
    public int minNumAllowed { get; set; }
    public int maxNumAllowed { get; set; }
    public string displayType { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string itemId { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public IList<Variation> variations { get; set; }
    public IList<IList<>> variationsChoices { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public IList<OrderItem> orderItems { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried creating a class:

```
public class VariationChoice
{
    public IList<string> itemIds { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

and changing the OrderItem class to:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public string itemId { get; set; }
    public IList<Variation> variations { get; set; }
    public IList<VariationChoice> variationsChoices { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string comment {get; set;}
}
```

but I get an error when I try to Deserialize the JSON file with

```
Root Wix;
        try
        {
            Wix = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

The error is:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WebHook_Receiver.Models.VariationChoice' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path 'order.orderItems[3].variationsChoices[0]', line 21903, position 6.

Can you help please?

Comment: looks like an array of arrays, have you tried `public IList<VariationChoice[]> variationsChoices { get; set; }`? and change your `VariationChoice` class to use a single `string` value of the `itemId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating a class containing an array of strings and an int type.

```
 public class VariationChoice
 {
    public IList<string> itemIds { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
 }
```

but here you are declaring a member of type array of array, with the inner array containing one string member and one numeric member

```
"variationsChoices": [
                [
                    {
                        "itemId": "86bef61f-a59f-4c1f-88a6-009594ed1f54",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            ],
```

The serializer does not konw how to "translate" from json type to c# type because they are not compatible

```
public class VariationChoices
  {
      public IList<VariationChoices> variationChoices { get; set; }
  }

  public class VariationChoice
  {
      public string itemId { get; set; }
      public int count { get; set; }
  }
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @Ryan Wilson and @CaveCoder. You are both correct in pointing out that VariationChoices is an array of arrays. The solution that worked for me was:

```
 public class OrderItem
{
    public string itemId { get; set; }
    public IList<Variation> variations { get; set; }
    public IList<IList<VariationChoice>> variationsChoices { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string comment {get; set;}
}
```

and create a class

```
public class VariationChoice
{
    public string itemId { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

I got to this answer by combining both your answers. Many thanks again